# Yii2 DatePicker onSelect not called

Tags: jquery, datepicker, yii2

I have a DatePicker Widget:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'startDate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
      'clientOptions' => [
        'maxViewMode' => 2,
        'todayBtn' => "linked",
        'daysOfWeekDisabled' => "0,1",
        'autoclose' => true,
        'onSelect' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(dateText, inst) { console.log(dateText, inst) }')
      ],
      'language' => 'fr'
    ])?>
```

But I do not see anything happening when selecting a date, what am I missing?

---

### **Update (1)**

I tried with two DatePicker:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'startDate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
      'clientOptions' => [
        'maxViewMode' => 2,
        'todayBtn' => "linked",
        'daysOfWeekDisabled' => "0,1",
        'autoclose' => true,
        'onSelect' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(dateText, inst) { alert("Hi"); }')
      ],
      'language' => 'fr'
    ])?>
    </div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'stopDate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
      'clientOptions' => [
        'maxViewMode' => 2,
        'todayBtn' => "linked",
        'daysOfWeekDisabled' => "0,1",
        'autoclose' => true,
        'onSelect' => 'alert("Hi")'
      ],
      'language' => 'fr'
    ]) ?>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript generated:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#bookingform-startdate').datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['fr'], {"maxViewMode":2,"todayBtn":"linked","daysOfWeekDisabled":"0,1","autoclose":true,"onSelect":function(dateText, inst) { alert("Hi"); },"dateFormat":"d M yy"}));
$('#bookingform-stopdate').datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['fr'], {"maxViewMode":2,"todayBtn":"linked","daysOfWeekDisabled":"0,1","autoclose":true,"onSelect":"alert(\u0022Hi\u0022)","dateFormat":"d M yy"}));
});
```

Btw the language doesn't work either, maybe both problems are linked?

Comment: Do you have tried something more direct such as `onSelect => 'alert("Hi")'`

Comment: Does not work either :/

Comment: Did you check the HTML output of the widget from the page source in the browser?

Comment: Could you check my update and tell me if it's helping you finding out what's wrong? Thx

Comment: Check also broser's console

Comment: Nothing happen on the browser console